# Read input from StdIn, Require performance improvemnent with respect to run time, request suggestions

Tags: scala, scala-collections

I am trying to submit below scala solution in hacker earth memorize me!. but, it is not taking due to Time limit exceeded.

Any suggestions on how i can improve the run time ?

I see with timer, readInt in loop(2nd for loop) is taking more time, as the input increases.... need thoughts any other methods i can use to improve this ?

```
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit

import scala.collection.mutable.{ArrayBuffer, Map}
import scala.io.StdIn.{readInt, readLine}

import scala.io.Source.stdin

object MemorizeMe {

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {

    var inpLen = readInt()
    var inp = readLine().split(" ").map(_.toInt)

    val numQueries = readInt()
    var queryList = new ArrayBuffer[Int]

    var numsMap = Map[Int, Int]()
    time {for (i <- inp) if (numsMap.contains(i)) numsMap(i) = numsMap(i) + 1 else numsMap += (i -> 1)}

    time{for (i <- 1 to numQueries) queryList += readInt()}
    time{for(i <- queryList) if (numsMap.contains(i)) println(numsMap(i)) else println("NOT PRESENT")}

    /*for (x <- io.Source.stdin.getLines) {
      val i = x.toInt
      if (numsMap.contains(i)) println(numsMap(i)) else println("NOT PRESENT")
    }*/

  }

  def time[R](block: => R): R = {
    val t0 = System.nanoTime()
    val result = block    // call-by-name
    val t1 = System.nanoTime()
    println(TimeUnit.SECONDS.convert((t1 - t0), TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS) + "secs")
    result
  }

}
```

Comment: Could you post the time measurements you get for each for?

Answer (score 1):

You have the information about how many integers you will receive. You can use that information to create an `Array` of fixed size and change the appends (`queryList += readInt()`) to updates (`queryList(i) = readInt()`).

As you can find in Scala doc (https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/collections/performance-characteristics.html) append cost is `aC` meanwhile update cost is `C`.

Comment: sure, i will try the thought, and let you know .... !

While i will try the suggestion, but, what i felt the actual time is going high because of reading input from StdIn, on every itereation... rather than array append..... !

Comment: @Raja What are the time measurements you get? Just to understand the time scale that we are talking about here.

Comment: for 1000 numbers, below for loop is taking 40secs.

    time{for (i <- 1 to numQueries) queryList += readInt()}

Comment: @Raja have you tried to read the entire input at once? instead of doing many read statements? That will probably increase the performance substantially

Comment: yeah want to read all input at one shot, but i couldn't find api call out there to do that...

Comment: i see a method in  scala.io.Source.stdin.getlines(), but i couldn't find an example on its usage..... or any other thoughts you may have....

Comment: You can try using Java io library, which you can easily use from Scala (just by importing it). You will find plenty of examples for that one.

Answer (score 0):

Not tested, but this should work:

```
val queryList = Array.fill(numQueries)(ReadInt())
```

This will allocate an `Array` of the correct size and then call `ReadInt` for each element.

Comment: thanks for the response. But, unfortunately, this approach did not reduced time its taking for the program...

Comment: Did it affect the time taken for this loop? Where is most of the time going?

Comment: i did not see any time improve with the change. 

I see most of the time is going in readInt method for second loop.

Comment: here is the hackerearth problem i am trying to solve ...

https://www.hackerearth.com/practice/data-structures/arrays/1-d/practice-problems/algorithm/memorise-me/